# Почему не выводиться результат запроса в блок pre?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему не выводиться результат в блок pre, при этом никаких ошибок нет

**module.js:**

```js
export async function getSwapiData(start, end) {
    let response = await fetch(`${start}/${end}`, {
        method: 'GET',
    });
    try {
        return {
            status: 'success',
            data: response.json(),
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return {
            status: 'error',
            data: null
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.js:**

```js
class Swapi {
    constructor(params) {
        const { form, elPre, elController, elId, elLoader } = params;
        this.elForm = document.querySelector(`.${form}`);
        this.elPre = elPre;
        this.elController = elController;
        this.elId = elId;
        this.elLoader = elLoader;
        this.elForm.addEventListener('submit', this.formSubmit)
    }



    formSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.elLoader.classList.remove('d-none');
        const { getSwapiData } = await import('./module.js');
        const formData = new FormData(this.elForm);
        const formAction = this.elForm.action
        const formURL = formData.get('url');
        // console.log('formURL: ', formURL);
        // console.log('getSwapiData: ', await getSwapiData(this.elForm.action, formURL));
        const regExp = /\//;
        const hasSlash = regExp.test(formURL);
        if (hasSlash) {
            const trimURL = formURL.trim();
            const response = await getSwapiData(formAction, trimURL);
            // console.log('Response: ', response)
            this.showResponse(response, trimURL)
        } else {
            alert('Введите /');
            this.elLoader.classList.add('d-none')
        }
    }
    showResponse = (response, url) => {
        if (response?.status === 'success') {
            const getURLInfo = url.split('/');
            this.elController.classList.remove('d-none');
            this.elController.innerHTML = getURLInfo[0];
            const id = getURLInfo[1];
            if (id) {
                this.elId.classList.remove('d-none');
                this.elId.innerHTML = id;
            } else {
                this.elId.classList.add('d-none')
            }
            this.elPre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2);
        } else {
            this.elController.classList.add('d-none');
            this.elId.classList.add('d-none');
            this.elPre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)
        }
        this.elLoader.classList.add('d-none');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const swapi = new Swapi({
        form: 'js--swapi_form',
        elPre: document.querySelector('.js--swapi_pre'),
        elController: document.querySelector('.js--swapi_controller'),
        elId: document.querySelector('.js--swapi_id'),
        elLoader: document.querySelector('.js--swapi_load'),
    })
})
```

```css
.card {
 position: relative;
}
.load {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: calc(50% - 18px);
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <h1>SWAPI</h1>
    <form action="https://swapi.dev/api" class="input-group mb-3 js--swapi_form">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://swapi.dev/api</span>
        <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control js--swapi_input" id="basic-url" placeholder="/people/1/" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Get info</button>
    </form>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <span class="badge d-none bg-secondary js--swapi_controller">people</span>
            <span class="badge d-none bg-secondary js--swapi_id">1</span>
            <div class="load d-none js--swapi_load">
                <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <pre class="mt-2 mb-0 js--swapi_pre"></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте отдебажить код...........и ещё.... module.js  и Module.js - это нормально что имена различаются?